# React Router - page is not re-rendered at route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a simple app where I try to interchange between 2 routes, and for each route there is a specific component to be rendered. Unfortunately, it seems like it remains **stuck** on the *first* `Route` I set inside the `Switch`.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-kilby-gqlq1) you can access a sandbox containing the simplified app. I have set **2 NavLink** components to *manage* the **2 routes**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the builer component, you should use path instead to :

```
            <Route path="/checkout" exact render={() => <div>Checkout</div>} />

            <Route path="/" exact>
              {this.state.showModal ? <div>Modal {orderSummary}</div> : null}

              <div>Main Page</div>

              {this.state.error ? errorMessage : ingredientControls}
            </Route>
```

I tried it, it's work